# What is wrong in my opencart configurations?

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to access the admin page of my opencart but I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getFirstName() on a non-object in /home/xxxxxx/public_html/catalog/controller/common/header.php on line 73

I am not an expert in opencart but I don't think the admin should be accessing a file from the catalog.

really, the configurations seem right.
Did anyone ever see this error before?

This is the line `73` which is being acused in the error:

```
$this->data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
```

---

Thank you everyone. The error was that I copied the wrong file and was dumb enough to not read the code thoroughly. Thank you guys

Comment: I suspect it is a file that didn't upload correctly

Comment: you can edit your post, and I edited my comment was thinking about something else when I commented, I think it should be some file that didn't upload correctly

Comment: I am uploading it again. but I can't think of which file it could be.

Comment: here is a link that may help: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=24313

Comment: yes, I googled it before and I found this especific topic. but those guys are refering to the admin/controller/common/header.php file, my site is acusing the catalog/controller/common/header.php, for some reason... still googling

Comment: The configuration data isn't of any relevance to this question. Edit that out and show your file `catalog/controller/common/header.php` - better still, just show what is on line 73 of that file

Comment: there it is. but I think it is an include somewhere

Comment: I have others opencart sites running just fine. I tryed to insert errors on those site's catalog/controller/common/header.php file.
And as expected, the error showed up in the catalog/ not in the admin/, that is why I believe that the error is an include somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked both config files, in admin folder and the one in root, if they are configured correctly both?

The one you are showing is the one in root area, please check also the one in the admin area.
Also try adding:

```
define('HTTPS_ADMIN', 'http://yourdomain.com/admin/');
```

Admin config should also look something like this:

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://yourdomain.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://yourdomain.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://yourdomain.com/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://yourdomain.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://yourdomain.com/image/');
define('HTTPS_CATALOG', 'http://yourdomain.com/');
```

If these are setup like this, then surely there  something buggy in the code.

Comment: I feel so dumb right now. I must have copied the wrong config file while comparing one with the other. I didn't read the code thoroughly. Sorry and thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
$this->data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_logged'), $this->url->link('account/account', '', 'SSL'), $this->customer->getFirstName(), $this->url->link('account/logout', '', 'SSL'));
                    =>                                    =>                                          =>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

At administration, `$this->customer` is null, as `$customer` is not registered (in opposite to catalog, where the `$user` is missing). Instead of this in administration the `$user` object is registered, so You can call `$this->user`.

Therefore You need to call this:

```
$this->user->getUserName()
```

instead of

```
$this->customer->getFirstName()
```

If You would like to get the firstname of the logged in user instead, You'd have to edit the core file `system/library/user.php` and add the method and logic for retrieving the user's firstname by Yourself.